# How do I upload file to OneDrive from PHP without any user intervention?

Tags: php, onedrive

I have a client who requires files to be autonomously uploaded to their organisation's OneDrive directory. This upload needs to be fully automated and will need to run without any human intervention whatsoever. I have read through lots of MicroSoft documentation as well as other similar questions, but all of the solutions that I've found has a step that requires the user to be directed to the sign in page. In my case, there is no user and there is no browser involved. Ideally a PHP SDK would help, but if I can do this via pure HTTP requests, that would also work.

I have tried several PHP SDK's, all of which require some degree of human interaction.

Comment: This should be possible by creating an app registration in Azure with application-level Graph API permissions to write files in OneDrive, have you evaluated this yet?

Comment: Hi, yes, that part is done. However, I'm struggling to authenticate within PHP without requiring a user to sign in on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to achive this via SharePoint by using the SDK found [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/tree/dev). Code below in case anyone else is struggling with this.

```
define('MS_URL', 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token');

    //Authenticate
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $url = MS_URL;
    $token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, array('form_params' => array('client_id' => MS_CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret' => MS_CLIENT_SECRET, 'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default', 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials')))->getBody()->getContents());
    $access_token = $token->access_token;

    //Upload
    $graph = new \Microsoft\Graph\Graph();
    $graph->setBaseUrl('https://graph.microsoft.com/')->setApiVersion('v1.0')->setAccessToken($access_token);
    $graph->createRequest('PUT', '/sites/'.MS_SHAREPOINT_BACKUP_SITE_ID.'/drive/root:/'.$new_filename.':/content')->upload($path_to_local_file);
```